# Running docker run in Chef

Tags: linux, docker, chef-infra, redhat, chef-recipe

I am looking to make Chef manage running docker containers. However I am not sure how to move forward. This the `docker run` command which I use today and want to make it Chef friendly and move it into my recipies:

```
docker run --name=nginx--restart=unless-stopped -p 443:443 -p 80:80 --privileged=true -v /etc/php:/conf/stack -v /var/www/html -d repository.com/nginx:v1.5.3
```

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: `I am looking to make Chef manage running docker containers.` - why?

Comment: @johnharris85 - Because I want Chef to handle my containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "official" Docker cookbook from Chef's Supermarket -  https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker

Then as an example you can do:

```
# Pull latest image
docker_image 'nginx' do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
  notifies :redeploy, 'docker_container[my_nginx]'
end

# Run container mapping containers port 80 to the host's port 80
docker_container 'my_nginx' do
  repo 'nginx'
  tag 'latest'
  port '80:80'
  host_name 'www'
  domain_name 'computers.biz'
  env 'FOO=bar'
  volumes [ '/some/local/files/:/etc/nginx/conf.d' ]
end
```

Comment: It seems that the cookbook does not support the Redhat platform.